# glew warnings, problematic compilation in CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, glut, glew

Recently, I have finally managed to compile simple glut project on Windows using GLEW libraries. But I have two problems:

1.When I do Build->Clean and then Build->Build I get about 3000 warnings like this:

```
D:\PBL\code blocks project\shikaku\glew.c|282|warning: '__glewCopyTexSubImage3D'    redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
```

However, the project compiles successfully and .exe file is generated. Then, when I compile the project again (after some changes), there no warnings or errors.
I defined GLEW_STATIC before everything, so I don't know what causes those warnings.

2.The second problem is more serious. I tried to compile the same project on another PC. I think I added all needed libraries to CodeBlocks, but the project cannot compile.

Apart from the warnings described as the first problem, I got two errors:

```
\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\glut32.lib No such file or directory
\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\OPENGL32.LIB No such file or directory
```

Of course, I've placed these files there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to link these libraries. Go to project tab-> select Build options
From there click linker setting tab then add these libraries.

Comment: Of course, I tried this, but it didn't work...